# Oracle - How to Capture a value Under an XML TAG

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

Need Help with the below.
If i wanted to  capture a value for a particular tag , how do i approach the same ?. for example

I  wanted to capture the value(800.422.2762 (U.S. and Canada)) from the highlighted tag .

```
<text top="89" left="611" width="177" height="11" font="1">800.422.2762 (U.S. and Canada)</text>
```

in short , I wanted to hardcode this tag to capture the underlying value every time my program runs .

**Sample XML:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pdf2xml producer="popple`enter code here`r" version="0.51.0">
<page number="1" position="absolute" top="0" left="0" height="1188" width="918">
   <fontspec id="0" size="27" family="Helvetica" color="#000000"/>
   <fontspec id="1" size="9" family="Helvetica" color="#000000"/>
   <fontspec id="2" size="9" family="Helvetica" color="#000000"/>
   <fontspec id="3" size="9" family="Times" color="#000000"/>
   <fontspec id="4" size="12" family="Helvetica" color="#000000"/>
   <fontspec id="5" size="12" family="Helvetica" color="#000000"/>
   <fontspec id="6" size="9" family="Helvetica" color="#000000"/>
<image top="27" left="54" width="203" height="108" src="ext-resources\bin\asdf-1_1.jpg"/>
<text top="103" left="346" width="123" height="28" font="0"><b>INVOICE</b></text>
<text top="75" left="611" width="211" height="11" font="1">+1 913.217.6000, Fax +1 913.341.3742</text>
<text top="89" left="611" width="177" height="11" font="1">800.422.2762 (U.S. and Canada)</text>
<text top="102" left="611" width="230" height="11" font="1">headquarters@armaintl.org, www.arma.org</text>
<text top="32" left="611" width="104" height="11" font="1">ARMA International</text>
</page>
</pdf2xml>
```

**So far, i have tried the below approach.**
I am succeeded in extracting the data but i wanted to extract a particular value based on the hard coded tag. Kindly Help with the approach.

```
WITH data
     AS (SELECT xmltype (
                   '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pdf2xml producer="popple`enter code here`r" version="0.51.0">
<page number="1" position="absolute" top="0" left="0" height="1188" width="918">
   <fontspec id="0" size="27" family="Helvetica" color="#000000"/>
   <fontspec id="1" size="9" family="Helvetica" color="#000000"/>
   <fontspec id="2" size="9" family="Helvetica" color="#000000"/>
   <fontspec id="3" size="9" family="Times" color="#000000"/>
   <fontspec id="4" size="12" family="Helvetica" color="#000000"/>
   <fontspec id="5" size="12" family="Helvetica" color="#000000"/>
   <fontspec id="6" size="9" family="Helvetica" color="#000000"/>
<image top="27" left="54" width="203" height="108" src="ext-resources\bin\asdf-1_1.jpg"/>
<text top="103" left="346" width="123" height="28" font="0"><b>INVOICE</b></text>
<text top="75" left="611" width="211" height="11" font="1">+1 913.217.6000, Fax +1 913.341.3742</text>
<text top="89" left="611" width="177" height="11" font="1">800.422.2762 (U.S. and Canada)</text>
<text top="102" left="611" width="230" height="11" font="1">headquarters@armaintl.org, www.arma.org</text>
<text top="32" left="611" width="104" height="11" font="1">ARMA International</text>
</page>
</pdf2xml>')
                   xmldoc
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT x.*
  FROM data,
       XMLTABLE ('/pdf2xml/page/text'
                 PASSING xmldoc
                 COLUMNS text VARCHAR2 (50) PATH '/text') x
/
```

Output:

```
TEXT
--------------------------------------------------
INVOICE
+1 913.217.6000, Fax +1 913.341.3742
800.422.2762 (U.S. and Canada)
headquarters@armaintl.org, www.arma.org
ARMA International
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have one source document and only want one node value, you could use XMLQuery instead of XMLTable, with a slightly variation on @wolφi's XPath:

```
select XMLQuery('/pdf2xml/page/text[@top=89]/text()'
  passing xmldoc
  returning content) as text
from data;
```

which gives you an XML fragment, or

```
select XMLQuery('/pdf2xml/page/text[@top=89]/text()'
  passing xmldoc
  returning content).getStringVal() as text
from data;
```

which gives you a string:

```
TEXT                          
------------------------------
800.422.2762 (U.S. and Canada)
```

XMLTable is the way to go if you really have multiple documents or nodes though, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Just change the XQuery from

```
'/pdf2xml/page/text'
```

to

```
'/pdf2xml/page/text[@top=89]'
```

and the result will be

```
800.422.2762 (U.S. and Canada)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or change the query into:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM data,
   XMLTABLE ('/pdf2xml/page/text'
             PASSING xmldoc
             COLUMNS 
             text VARCHAR2 (50) PATH '/text',
             top  number        PATH '@top',
             left  number       PATH '@left',
             width  number      PATH '@width',
             height  number     PATH '@height',
             font    number     PATH '@font'
             ) x
where x.top = 89
and x.left = 611
and x.width = 177
and x.height = 11
and x.font = 1;
```